# Wordpress Search return 500 when nothing found ( memory_limit exausted)

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Im on wordpress 5.3.2, no plugin on search, tested on différent server, 
When searching for "xxxxx" (no post found) i always get a 500 ( memory_limit ).

After looking for everythings i know  ( tested the query , everythings looks right ) I am asking you guys if have any idea how to check for this ...

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a blank text file called php.ini
2. Paste this code in there: memory=64MB
3. Save the file
4. Upload it into your /wp-admin/ folder using FTP

Comment: I tested with 4G memory_limit, still the same 500

Answer (score 0):

AutoAnswers after some research, the theme is use doesn't have a " Not found page" after a search.